# Loading data in Powerpoint array with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to load data in Powerpoint VBA array from Excel. This data will be used later to perform find/replace in powerpoint. I get stuck at the last line of the code below. I accepted this code to load the array for future operations:

```
Dim FindList As Variant '<- this is array to be loaded with data
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Boxync\findreplace.xlsx")
Set FindList = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `Set`. If you delete it, your code should work.
To make it a bit better, you can use `Application.Transpose()`:

```
With xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    FindList = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A4").Value2)
End With
```

Then access the array like this - `FindList(1)`, `FindList(2)`.